# How do I make block level anchor tags accessible?

Tags: html, accessibility

I need to make a website accessible for assistive technology. One issue I have is with a block level anchor tag. The code is similar to this:

```
<a href="/page">
  <div class="text">
    <h2>Mammals</h2>
    <p>We have a large selection of dogs, cats, and hamsters.</p>
    <p class="link-description">Explore Mammals</p>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="/cat.jpg" alt="Black cat in a tree" />
  </div>
</a>
```

My goal is to have the entire block (The image, heading, paragraph text, and both div's) clickable but for screen readers to read the link as "Explore Mammals" instead of "Mammals We have a large selection of dogs, cats, and hamsters. Explore Mammals Black cat in a tree." In addition, this is a responsive site so the div's are side by side on desktop but stacked on mobile and the two div's animate in when the page is scrolled.

Does anyone have ideas on how to overcome the accessibility issue described?

Answer (score 2):

That is not an accessibility issue, that is a usability issue. Screen readers just happen to be the audience most affected by it.

In this case you can use `aria-label` on the `<a>` to override the content within. Depending on your screen reader it may read the image separately but still use the `aria-label` text.

```
<a href="/page" aria-label="Explore Mammals">
  <div class="text">
    <h2>Mammals</h2>
    <p>We have a large selection of dogs, cats, and hamsters.</p>
    <p class="link-description">Explore Mammals</p>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="/cat.jpg" alt="Black cat in a tree" />
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Do this instead: https://adrianroselli.com/2020/02/block-links-cards-clickable-regions-etc.html